# Weibull distribution

Tags: self-study, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, fisher-information

I need to find a distribution that fail regularity condition.Maybe weibull distribution can be but I did not find why, please help me.

[image]

Comment: The easiest one to see a violation of immediately is 3. Look at what happens with a normal whose variance is a function of its mean (i.e $\sigma^{2} = \mu^{2}$)

Comment: What made you think the Weibull might be an example?

Answer (score 1):

A classical example for 2. is given by the uniform distribution $U(0,\theta)$, which has density $1/\theta$ *if* $0\leq x \leq\theta$. So, the support depends on the parameter.

This also results in an MLE, viz. $\max_i(X_i)$, that violates 5., as the likelihood is 0 to the left of the MLE and $1/\theta^n$ to the right, hence the first derivative does not have slope zero at the maximum.

Comment: I fear this may go a bit beyond the 'hints and guidance' requested for answering homework/self study questions - http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info . (Something to consider for future answers at least.)

Comment: I know uniform distribution that fail for regularity condition .But I need find another distribution will you know distribution that depends on parameter like uniform distribution or can I find distribution that fisher information is negative? Also this is not a homework question. I learnt uniform distrubition in class and I wonder can I find another distribution that fail. @ChristophHanck

Comment: OK, it would have been useful to clarify that in advance. Check Pareto for another example.

Comment: Thank you, which one ıs failing for pareto ? I could not find. @ChristophHanck

Comment: can you help me please I checked Fisher information that is positive.

Comment: It is another example where the support depends on a parameter. I am not aware of a distribution with negative Fisher information.